How to assume "much greater than" when there are multiple assumptions?
Assume $r_{o1} \gg R_S, r_{o2} \gg R_S, g_{m1} r_{o1} \gg 1, g_{m2} r_{o2} \gg 1$.
$$Z_{out} = \frac{r_{o1} (R_S + r_{o2})} {r_{o2} + R_S (1- g_{m1} g_{m2} r_{o1} r_{o2})}$$
Here is what I tried to add those condition.
This is what I have learnt from  this post
Zout = ro1 (RS + ro2)/(ro2 + RS (1 - gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2));
Series[Zout, {gm1 ro1, \[Infinity], 1}, {gm2 ro2, \[Infinity], 1}]
Series[Zout, {RS, 0, 1}]

However, this gives me an error.
The simplified version of my equation should become this below according to my hand-written analysis
$$Z_{out} = \frac{1} {-g_{m1} g_{m2}  R_S}$$
In my opinion, these conditions should be met simultaneously ($r_{o1} \gg R_S, r_{o2} \gg R_S, g_{m1} r_{o1} \gg 1, g_{m2} r_{o2} \gg 1$.)

You don't actually state a question or what you want. It seems you want only that the code not give errors, but then you keep asking @evanb questions after they answer. Please clarify what you're trying to obtain. Tx.

Your handwritten needs three assumptions ro1>>RS, ro2>>RS, ro2<<RS gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2 I think.

I think only the former 2 conditions are needed?: Limit[ro1 (RS + ro2)/(ro2 + RS (1 - gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2)) /. {ro1 -> inf RS, ro2 -> inf RS}, inf -> Infinity] If one needs a multivariate limit: Limit[ro1 (RS + ro2)/(ro2 + RS (1 - gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2)) /. {ro1 ->      inf1 RS, ro2 -> inf2 RS}, {inf1, inf2} -> {Infinity, Infinity}] The results are the same.

@xzczd No I don't think so. If you simplify expression Zout you get Zout=ro1 (1+Rs/ro2)/(1+RS/ro2-RS/ro2 gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2) . To evaluate the limit you need to know RS/ro2 gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2>>1 or RS/ro2 gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2<<1 .

@UlrichNeumann I think I see the issue. My calculation essentially makes use of the following equivalent form: (RS/ro2 + 1)/((1/RS + 1/ro2) (RS/ro1) - RS gm1 gm2). From this it's easy to see that, we can deduce -(1/(gm1 gm2 RS)) as long as (1/RS + 1/ro2) isn't too large. I think the root of the problem is, "much greater than" isn't a well-defined math concept, so different interpretation will lead to different result.

@xzczd Agreed, thanks for your reply!

As mentioned in my last comment, "much greater than" isn't a well-defined math concept, and by reading the question, it's not clear how OP has interpreted it. Personally I think this is more of a math problem and should be discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/ . If OP insists on discussing it here, the hand-written analysis should be added to the question to clarify the ambiguity. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

As you wrote it, your first invocation of Series produces errors,
Series::ivar: gm1 ro1 is not a valid variable.
Series::ivar: gm2 ro2 is not a valid variable.

What this is trying to tell you is that you can't use a product as the expansion variable in a series, because in the general case there's ambiguity about what to do if one of the factors appears alone.
Indeed, in your case we could do
substituted = Zout /. {gm1 -> \[Lambda]1/ro1, gm2 -> \[Lambda]2/ro2}
result1 = (Normal@Series[substituted, 
    {\[Lambda]1, \[Infinity], 1},
    {\[Lambda]2, \[Infinity], 1}]
) /. {\[Lambda]1 -> gm1  ro1, \[Lambda]2 -> gm2  ro2}
(* -((ro2+RS)/(gm1 gm2 ro2 RS)) *)

Or, we could make a different substitution
substituted = Zout /. {ro1 -> \[Lambda]1/gm1, ro2 -> \[Lambda]2/gm2}
result2 = (Normal@Series[substituted,
    {\[Lambda]1, \[Infinity], 1},
    {\[Lambda]2, \[Infinity], 1}]
) /. {\[Lambda]1 -> gm1  ro1, \[Lambda]2 -> gm2  ro2}
(* -((ro2+gm1 gm2 ro1 ro2 RS+RS (2+gm1 gm2 ro1 RS))/(gm1^2 gm2^2 ro1 ro2 RS^2)) *)

and result1 != result2.  So what you mean is critically important.
You might also mean the simultaneous limit,
substituted = (Zout /. {gm1 -> \[Lambda]  gm1, gm2 -> \[Lambda] gm2})
result3 = Normal@Series[substituted,
    {\[Lambda], \[Infinity], 2}
] /. {\[Lambda] -> 1}
(* same as result1 *)

with one control parameter.

Isn't the result should $-\frac{1} {g_{m1} g_{m2} R_S}$

How can you add constraints $r_{o1} \gg R_S, r_{o2} \gg R_S$?

Well, one way to get what you think the result ought to be is Normal@Series[result1 /. ro2 -> c  RS, {c, \[Infinity], 0}].  Another way is Normal@Series[result2 /. {ro1 -> c1  RS, ro2 -> c2  RS}, {c1, \[Infinity], 0}, {c2, \[Infinity], 0}].

Or Series[Zout, ro1 -> ∞, ro2 -> ∞] but not
Series[Zout, gm1 -> ∞, gm2 -> ∞], which suggests to me the question needs some clarification. @kile Is it clear which are independent variables and which are parameters?

@MichaelE2 $g_{m1}, g_{m2}$ are independent of each other. Also,  $r_{o1}, r_{o2}$ are independent of each other

@kile That's not what I meant. For a simpler example, consider $y=\cos \omega t$. Often we think of $\omega$ as a (constant) parameter and $t$ as the independent variable; and $y$ is the dependent variable, representing a single-variable function of $t$ that depends on a parameter. It's possible to treat $y$ as a multivariate function of two independent variables, also. In the single-variable case, we might be interested in the dependence on $\omega$ of the asymptotics of $y$ as $t\rightarrow t_0$. In the multivariate case it might be the asymptotics as $(t,\omega)\rightarrow(t_0,\omega_0)$...

...If gm1 and gm2 are the independent variables, then Series[Zout, gm1 -> ∞, gm2 -> ∞] gives the result, but it is not the one you say it should be. Perhaps what you want to compute is Series[Zout, gm1 -> ∞, gm2 -> ∞, ro1 -> ∞, ro2 -> ∞], if Zout is principally a function of all four variables. Use Normal to get rid of the extraneous big-O's.

ReplaceAll::reps: {result2 (\[Lambda]1->gm1 ro1),result2 (\[Lambda]2->gm2 ro2)} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. 

What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to result2/.{your replacements}?
